# Is there a way to access the values of a dictionary by non-complete keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

I need a dictionary with a key of type string, but you don't need to enter the whole word to access the correspondent value, just some of the first characters, enough of them to don´t match any other key (similar to typing in a console, and press tab and the console guess the correct command because no other match it)

For example in the dictionary:

```
dicc = { 'suma':fun_suma, 'resta':fun_resta, 'producto':fun_producto }
```

I need that `dicc['pr']`, `dicc['prod']`, `dicc['produc']`, even just `dicc['p']`, return `fun_producto` (in this example, because the strings entered doesn't match any other key).

Is there any structure in python that makes that? If not, which algorithm do you suggest to build it? I know that behind any Python dictionary, there is an efficient tree of keys that lets found the asked key quickly. I would like to take advantage of that.

UPDATES:

1. Yes, I was wrong, Python dictionary uses a hash table, not a tree. I mixed my memories.
2. Yeah, `dicc['p']` was a dramatic example, but I used it just to show that in some cases it could abbreviate so much the entry of characters. Of course it will be useful only if the keys are well-known and a finite set, like a parser.

Comment: What should `dicc['p']` do if there is more than one key that starts with `p`?

Comment: Also, possible misconception - python dictionaries are not a 'tree of keys' as far as I know, just a flat hash.

Comment: One other thing: python is not C, your fastest implementation (even if it's algorithmically not optimal) will likely be to do a list comprehension on the keys looking for some pattern; you could implement a tree of dictionaries, but it would likely not be any faster. Also, you can do 'infix' matching with the flat case; that would require more work with the nested-dict approach.

Comment: A python `dict` object does not work like this, you will have to build your own data structure for this sort of thing. Maybe a *trie* fits your use-case.

Comment: " I know that behind any python diccionary, there is an efficient tree of keys that lets found the asked key quickly. " Absolutely incorrect. A python `dict` is implemented as a hash map (a fancy one), not as a tree map.  Of course, this is a CPytrhon implementation detail, but the data structure is so central to the language that I can't imagine an implementation not using a hash-map for it's specific performance characteristics.

Comment: Yeah @MarkMeyer, dicc['p'] was a dramatic example, but I used it just to show that in some cases it could abreviate so much the entry of caracteres. Of course it will be useful if the keys are well-known and a finite set, like a parser.

Comment: Maybe you got Python dicts mixed up with C++ `std::map`. `std::map` is a tree, but dicts definitely aren't.

Comment: they are closer to C++ `unordered_map` iirc.

Comment: No there’s nothing built-in to Python that does this. Of course you can define your own function/method to search the keys of the dictionary for what you could in some code-able way define as a ‘best match’. But what ‘best match’ means is rather subjective and is up to you to code. And part of this is how you must handle the situation where ‘p’ is present in more than one key.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/google/pygtrie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a simple dictionary subclass that overrides `__getitem__()` and returns values. You will probably want to prevent non-string keys, since dictionaries can have keys like numbers where prefixes don't make as much sense.

This might be a start, it will return the first key that matches the prefix:

```
from collections import UserDict

class PrefixDict(UserDict):
    def __setitem__(self, name, value):
        if not isinstance(name, str):
            raise ValueError("Keys must be strings")
        super().__setitem__(name, value)

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        try:
            return next(self.data[k] for k in self.data.keys() if k.startswith(name))
        except StopIteration as error:
            raise KeyError(f"Prefix '{name}' not found") from None

dicc = PrefixDict({'suma':'fun_suma', 'resta':'fun_resta', 'producto':'fun_producto' })

dicc['pr']
#'fun_producto'

dicc["q"]
# raises KeyError

dicc[""]
# ??
```

Instead of forcing keys to be strings, you could instead test in `__getitem__()` and defer non-string keys to the parent.